# Apache: python code execution error on Apache running on ubuntu 14.04 Server

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, cgi

I was trying to learn how to execute python code using Apache. Having gone through various tutorials, I configured my conf file
as follows to allow python code execution.

`000-default.conf`:

[image]

My python program, `hello.py` is following:

[image]

The program is put in directory `/var/www/html/cgi-bin/`. After Setting all this, When I goto address of file (`www.domainname.com/cgi-bin/hello.py`), I am met with following error.

[image]

How to resolve this error and get my code running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a handler in your python file.

```
from mod_python import apache

def handler(req):

    req.content_type = "text/plain"
    req.write("Hello World!")

    return apache.OK
```